# Upload file to Azure File Storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I am trying to upload a file to my Azure File Storage account.

This is my code:

```
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("myConnString");

        CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

        CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("myFileStorage");

        if (await share.ExistsAsync())
        {
            CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();
            CloudFileDirectory sampleDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference("/folder1/folder2/");
            CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("fileName.jpg");

            using Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(data);

            await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
        }
```

I am getting this error:

> The specified parent path does not exist.

After this line:

```
CloudFile file = sampleDir.GetFileReference("fileName");
```

the `file` has this uri:

```
https://myFileStorage.file.core.windows.net/myFileStorage/folder1/folder2/fileName.jpg
```

i.e. as expected.

Currently my file storage is empty, there are no files/folders. How do I create my custom folders if they do not already exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using [WindowsAzure.Storage, version 9.3.3](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WindowsAzure.Storage/) and create only one directory(no sub-directories), you can directly use `CreateIfNotExistsAsync()` method to create a directory.

But here is one thing you should remember, for file share, the SDK does not support create a directory which contains subdirectories, like "folder1/folder2" in your case. The solution for that is create these directories one by one.

Here is the sample code for your case, create a directory with sub-directories:

```
        static async void UploadFiles()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse("connection_string");

            CloudFileClient fileClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();

            CloudFileShare share = fileClient.GetShareReference("file_share");

            if (await share.ExistsAsync())
            {
                CloudFileDirectory rootDir = share.GetRootDirectoryReference();

                //define your directories like below:
                var myfolder = "folder1/folder2";

                var delimiter = new char[] { '/' };
                var nestedFolderArray = myfolder.Split(delimiter);
                for (var i = 0; i < nestedFolderArray.Length; i++)
                {
                    rootDir = rootDir.GetDirectoryReference(nestedFolderArray[i]);
                    await rootDir.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(rootDir.Name + " created...");
                }


                CloudFile file = rootDir.GetFileReference("fileName.jpg");

                byte[] data = File.ReadAllBytes(@"file_local_path");
                Stream fileStream = new MemoryStream(data);
                await file.UploadFromStreamAsync(fileStream);
            }

        }
```

The test result=> directories are created and file uploaded into azure:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `CloudFileDirectory.BeginCreateIfNotExists` method

[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.file.cloudfiledirectory.begincreateifnotexists?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Storage_File_CloudFileDirectory_BeginCreateIfNotExists_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_File_FileRequestOptions_Microsoft_Azure_Storage_OperationContext_System_AsyncCallback_System_Object_)